# MbUnit Rollback

Tags: c#, tdd, mbunit

I'm testing the MbUnit Framework and want to keep my test database in a persistent state after each test. How can I accomplish this?

This is what I'm trying, but my table is filled after the test is completed.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Gallio.Framework;
using MbUnit.Framework;

using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;

namespace BusinessLayer.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class PersonNHibernateTests
    {
        [Test] 
        [Rollback]
        public void CanSavePerson()
        {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.Configure();
            ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

            using (ISession session = factory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {

                    const string CONST_STR_FIRSTNAME = "Stephen";
                    const string CONST_STR_LASTNAME = "Manga";
                    DateTime birthdate = new DateTime(1974, 6, 20);

                    Person p = new Person
                    {
                        FirstName = CONST_STR_FIRSTNAME,
                        LastName = CONST_STR_LASTNAME,
                        Birthdate = birthdate
                    };

                    session.SaveOrUpdate(p);
                    session.Flush();

                    tx.Commit();

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Edit:

After some reading I've come to the understanding that Distributed Transaction Coordinator has to be enabled. After starting this service and testing still no success :(

Comment: Does updating MBUnit to version 3.0.6 help?

From [Announcing Gallio and MbUnit v3.0.6][1]
> Modified [Rollback] to enter a COM+ transaction context like MbUnit v2's original rollback attribute.  This should fix compatibility issues others have noted.


  [1]: http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2009/03/announcing-gallio-and-mbunit-v306.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a COMMIT statement in your code.  Perhaps you should remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just let System.Transactions.TransactionScope handle it?

```
using (new TransactionScope())
{
    // do stuff that gets automatically rolled back
}
```

Alternatively, this seems to be exactly what the MbUnit Rollback2 attribute does anyway (Rollback uses EnterpriseServices/COM+ and is aimed at .NET 1.1).

Comment: I am aware of the transaction scope, but I want to know how to do this with the MbUnit framework. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. The Rollback attribute is not the preferred approach - the Rollback2 attribute I believe is the preferred solution for .NET 2.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Proteus](http://unhandled-exceptions.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/16/proteus-unit-test-utility-and-domain-foundation-code-goes-oss/) it does just fine. Easy to setup and use.. 
All you need is to add some code to Setups TearDowns and prepare folder with 'snapshot' of your database.